# Python RegEx pattern seems to ignore part of the pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This is a bit of follow on from something I asked yesterday, as we are currently looking at other ways around what we are trying to do. We are opening a .bin file and find a certain pattern as it contains data we are after. So we are trying to look at regex matches to get this back, so far again it's in testing stages, we have the following:

```
import re,sys
f = open ('file.txt','w')       
file = open('file.bin', 'rb')
data = file.read()
messages=re.search(b'\x03\x07\x91\x44(.*)\xFF\xFF',data)
f.write(repr(messages))
```

It's basic, just opens up a file to write, opens up the file we are after then should search through for the string of bytes '\x03\x07\x91\x44 anything \xFF\xFF' Currently only after 1 match but will move to a findall once it's working, and reporting the finding to a file. But it is matching the following string:

match=b'\x03\x07\x91D\x97\x85x\x89\x97\x04\x0c\x91DW\x93>

It seems to ignore the \x44 totally and gathers anything after the 91, does anyone know how to fix this or am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 0):

It does actually find what you want. The character 'D' that is matched has an ascii value of 0x44

Comment: I'm not after ASCII value of x44 I'm looking for the byte 0x44, I thought the specifying the string as a byte should return the byte back not the matching ascii? Also it still doesn't end with 0xFF 0xFF?

Comment: In an ASCII file, every character is a byte, therefore it is matching that byte. Not sure about the FFs though

Comment: The file is a .bin file, the data inside is just hex values. We are looking to run through the file, grab the hex values we are interested in then convert the data we are after into ascii. The hex inside is 7bit PDU hex and has lots of padding (thus just looking for the groupings we are after).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use a double backslash for the regex?

```
\\x03\\x07\\x91\\x44(.*)\\xFF\\xFF
```

Does this help?

See: https://regex101.com/r/pF8gG1/1

Comment: and because it is a python string this might translate into 4 backslashes: `\\\\x03\\\\x07\\\\x91\\\\x44(.*)\\\\xFF\\\\xFF`

Comment: Thanks, we just tried this a second ago as we saw that also (and used a regex checker) it still returns  'match=b'\x03\x07\x91D\x97\x85x\x89\x97\x04\x0c\x91DW\x93>' as a match. When checking using the regex tester this shouldn't occur

Comment: and with the 4 backslashes?

Comment: With the 4 backslashes it reports no matches found. We know that the data is in this file however.

Comment: Sorry, but that's all I could think of. No more ideas.